# Tracking GST/VAT from invoice to payment

Tags: accounting, australia, double-entry

Contrived example: Alice and Bob both work for Charlie, who runs a lawnmowing service.  Charlie bills $100 plus 10% GST/VAT for the job. If Alice does the job, she gets $50 - if Bob does the job, he gets the $50.  At the end of the month, the GST has to be remitted to the government agency.  How does Charlie track the GST?

Charlie happens to be using ledger (https://www.ledger-cli.org/) but this question is about double-entry accounting, not the software.

Let's just say that Charlie is better at mowing lawns than accounting... but he's always willing to learn :-)

```
2019-01-01 invoice customer for Alice's work
    ; the customer is billed, and the total amount (GST included) is
    ; posted to Accounts Receivable.  Note there is no GST liability
    ; until the customer pays the bill.
    Assets:Accounts Receivable                110.00
    Income:Alice                             -110.00

2019-01-02 customer pays invoice
    ; the outstanding figure in Accounts Receivable is cleared to the
    ; bank account.  We now have a GST liability - but how do we
    ; properly account for this?
    Assets:Bank Account                       110.00
    Assets:Accounts Receivable               -110.00
    Liabilities:GST:Collected                 -10.00
    HELP PLEASE                                10.00

2019-01-03 pay Alice
    ; Alice gets paid - not complicated, that's an expense.
    Expenses:Salary                            50.00
    Assets:Bank Account                       -50.00

2019-02-01 remit GST
    ; the GST liability is cleared
    Assets:Bank Account                       -10.00
    Liabilities:GST:Collected                  10.00
```

Here are our balance sheets after each transaction:

After first transaction (customer invoiced):

```
         110  Assets:Accounts Receivable
        -110  Income:Alice
```

After second transaction (customer paid):

```
         110  Assets:Bank Account
          10  HELP PLEASE
        -110  Income:Alice
         -10  Liabilities:GST:Collected
```

After third transaction (Alice paid):

```
          60  Assets:Bank Account
          50  Expenses:Salary
          10  HELP PLEASE
        -110  Income:Alice
         -10  Liabilities:GST:Collected
```

After fourth/final transaction (GST remitted):

```
          50  Assets:Bank Account
          50  Expenses:Salary
          10  HELP PLEASE
        -110  Income:Alice
```

The first question pertains to the obviously named account "HELP PLEASE".

There is an additional (albeit intrinsically related) question: how do we track how much GST was paid?  When we pay GST, does this count as an Expense?

Comment: You might want to add a country tag. I track GST (Canada) separately from revenues & expenses. Sales and revenue $100. Tax collected is $10. Tax paid (Input tax Credits)  $0 . Net tax due $10. In Canada GST is accounted for as of invoice date, regardless of when the customer pays the invoice- if it's a bad debt you reclaim it.

Comment: Charlie runs his business on "cash basis" (as distinct from accrual basis) - this means income is only recognised when it is received (rather than when it was invoiced).

@SpehroPefhany: I have added the country tag as you suggested.  fyi: an Australian business can choose to use either cash or accrual basis.

Comment: We certainly need a "Cheatsheet" example of "invoicing and tax collection" to be clarified and added to the https://devhints.io/ledger and https://plaintextaccounting.org/#invoicing pages! I've been wondering about this same question fo years now :D

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT***

The $110 that you asked the customer to pay was always intended to be $100 in payment for the lawnmowing services, and $10 collected on behalf of the taxman.

I would suggest that the transactions on 2019-01-01 should be:

```
   Assets:Accounts Receivable                110.00
   Income:Alice                             -100.00
   Liabilities:GST:Collected                 -10.00
```

And when the customer pays:

```
    Assets:Bank Account                       110.00
    Assets:Accounts Receivable               -110.00
```

This process shows a GST liability somewhat earlier than the date when you have a **formal obligation** to pay GST to the Tax Office - but it has the advantage that the correct amount for the taxable service ($100) is shown on both your customer's invoice and in your books.

I'm not an accountant or a financial adviser, but I know that it would undesirable if the taxman had any reason to believe that GST should be paid on $110.  That would result in a tax liability that has to be paid partly out of your pocket

Comment: OP is in Australia where sales tax is due on the date you report your gross sales to the tax office and you may be forced to report monthly - it's a simple web form "i made $440,000 in sales, I spent $330,000, and I will pay $10,000 in tax immediately". You can base those figures on the invoice date, but if a lot of your customers haven't paid their bill yet... then you might be out of pocket a significant amount of money - tens of thousands of dollars, maybe hundreds of millions for a large corporation. And if Alice never pays the invoice, you've paid too much tax which is a headache.

Comment: If the chosen method of reporting allows for the reporting of money actually received, then Charlie is free to report on income received rather than amounts invoiced.  But the main point of my answer was that out of the $110 paid by the customer, only $100 was income belonging to Charlie's business.  The other $10 is NOT income, it's a tax payment (GST) collected by Charlie acting as an unpaid taxcollector on behalf of the government.